# How to tag two filters which are joined by "AND" operator in Solr?

Tags: solr, solrj, solrnet

I'm using Solr 4.0
I want to tag my two filters which joined by "AND" operators.

e.g query is

```
(f_Memory:1+GB) AND (Manufacturer:ASUS)
```

I want to tag like this

```
{!tag=dm}(f_Memory:1+GB) AND {!tag=dt}(Manufacturer:ASUS)
```

but I'm getting error

```
org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.ParseException: Cannot parse '(f_Memory:1+GB) AND {!tag=dt}(Manufacturer:ASUS)': Encountered " "}" "} "" at line 1, column 28.
Was expecting one of:
    "TO" ...
    <RANGE_QUOTED> ...
    <RANGE_GOOP> ..
```

Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try separating them as the effect of `AND` will be the same.

```
fq={!tag=dm}(f_Memory:1+GB)&fq={!tag=dt}(Manufacturer:ASUS)
```

Comment: but how to achieve this query in Solrnet?

Comment: just pass the values as the separate filter query values